# Adjust vertical spacing in tabular containing \href

Tags: tables, line-spacing, tabu

I seem to be stumped by what seems like a basic `tabular` spacing issue (when an `\href` is used). The obvious solution of tweaking `arraystretch` does not seem to work.

What I want is that the output of the `tabular` to look like the output of `itemize`, in terms of vertical spacing between the lines.  The first column below is the spacing that `itemize` produces and looks great.  The next two columns are what `tabular` and `tabu` produce with default settings:

[image]

As you can see, the lines in `tabular` and `tabu` are too close vertically.

So I thought that increasing the `\arraystretch` in `tabular`, or setting `\tabulinesep` in `tabu` should work just fine.  I wanted to avoid a manual solution of adding specifying the vertical space following a `\\`.  But even that does not work!

[image]

The columns above are:

1. the desired vertical spacing produced by `itemize`,
2. `tabular` with `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2.4}`,
3. `tabu` with `\tabulinesep=0.5ex`, and
4. manually added `\\[1.25ex]` at the end of the line:

Basically, I do *not* want the `\href` box to stretch, but do want the lines further apart.

### Notes:

- In only put these in `minipages` to make it easier to compare. In my really application they are below each other.  Plus this makes one nice wide image.  So, am *not* trying to get the baseline's aligned here.
- Now that I put this the two figures above it appears that the overlap does not change.  That seems to be a clue, but not sure how I can use that info.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\AddLinkToFile}[1]{\href{run:#1.pdf}{\strut#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{2.0cm}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \AddLinkToFile{a} b 
    \item \AddLinkToFile{c} d
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{2.0cm}
%\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2.4}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \AddLinkToFile{e} & f \\
    \AddLinkToFile{g} & h \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{2.0cm}
%\tabulinesep=0.5ex
\begin{tabu}{ll}
    \AddLinkToFile{i} & j \\
    \AddLinkToFile{k} & l \\
\end{tabu}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{2.0cm}%            Manually adding space
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \AddLinkToFile{l} & m \\[1.25ex]
    \AddLinkToFile{n} & o \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The default vertical space between consecutive items is controlled by `\itemsep+\parsep`, so the following should work: `\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \AddLinkToFile{e} & f \\[\dimexpr\itemsep+\parsep\relax]
    \AddLinkToFile{g} & h \\end{tabular}`

Comment: Yes, but that stretches out the `\href` box. Also would like to figure out how to automate it, as I have many tables in my document following an `itemize`.

Comment: @cmhughes and Gonzalo: I found a manual solution by an accident during copy and past error (forgot to remove the `\\ ` before pasting another one. The following works: `\\ \\[-4pt]`. The first `\\ ` makes sure the `\href` box is the correct size, and the second `\\[-4pt]` controls the spacing.  So, how do I automate this?

Comment: The 4pt is from `\itemsep`, so \\ \\[-\itemsep] should also work. Arghhh! How do you write \\ using code tags in comments?

Comment: Ok that explains the `4pt`.  The only way I found to show a `\\ `  is to leave a trailing space before the closing back tick.  So, now just need to figure out how to automate it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: See [my comment in the SE Sandbox](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208/formatting-sand-box#comment6573_208).

Comment: @Werner thank you! (I'll delete this comment shortly).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this'll help you:

- For the correct vertical spacing I will use [`listliketab`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listliketab)
- Amsmath's `\smash` is surprisingly helpful.

### Introducing to `\smash`

If I'd use

```
\newcommand*{\AddLinkToFile}[1]{\smash{\href{run:#1.pdf}{\strut#1}}}
```

The href-box becomes now a very small box (1pt height, 1pt depth?). This is also true for not-tabularized material.
[image: \smash{}]

### There are *three* optional argument to `\smash`

After playing around with `[b]` and `[t]` to see its effect I tried

```
\newcommand*{\AddLinkToFile}[1]{\smash[]{\href{run:#1.pdf}{\strut#1}}}
```

which does wonders:
[image: \smash[]{…}]

(The height and depth of the resulting box comes from `\strut`.)
Bug or feature? I don't know …

*But* every use of `\strut` (`[t]`, `[b]`, `[]` or no optional at all) breaks the `\AddLinkToFile` in a real `itemize` environment unless you add a `\leavevmode` in front of it.

**So the final `\AddLinkToFile` command would be:**

```
\newcommand*{\AddLinkToFile}[1]{\leavevmode\smash[]{\href{run:#1.pdf}{\strut#1}}}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\AddLinkToFile}[1]{\leavevmode\smash[]{\href{run:#1.pdf}{\strut#1}}}
%\renewcommand*{\AddLinkToFile}[1]{#1} % for my own testing purposes
\storestyleof{itemize}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \AddLinkToFile{a} b 
    \item \AddLinkToFile{c} d
\end{itemize}

\AddLinkToFile{A}

\begin{minipage}{2.0cm}
\begin{listliketab}
  \begin{tabular}{Ll}
    \textbullet & \AddLinkToFile{a} A \\
    \textbullet & \AddLinkToFile{c} d
  \end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{2.0cm}
\begin{listliketab}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2.4}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \AddLinkToFile{e} & f \\
    \AddLinkToFile{g} & h
\end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{2.0cm}
\begin{listliketab}
\tabulinesep=0.5ex
\begin{tabu}{ll}
    \AddLinkToFile{i} & j \\
    \AddLinkToFile{k} & l
\end{tabu}
\end{listliketab}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{2.0cm}
\begin{listliketab}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \AddLinkToFile{l} & m \\[1.25ex]
    \AddLinkToFile{n} & o
\end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well that seems to fix the `tabular` issue, but creates an issue for `itemize`?