# How can I make a custom \item for use in a list?

Tags: macros, lists, color, itemize

I would like to change the color of an `\item` in a list and I would like the item to look like a regular item.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item item one
\reditem item two
\item item three
\end{itemize}
```

and have "item two" be red and leave the font color of everything else alone?

I've looked and my google-fu is weak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `\specialitems` you can switch between different styles:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newcommand{\specialitems}{%
  \let\olditem\item% Store old \item in \olditem
  \newcommand{\reditem}{\olditem\leavevmode\color{red}}%
  \renewcommand{\item}{\color{black}\olditem\leavevmode}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\specialitems
\item item one
\reditem item two
\item item three
\end{itemize}
\end{document}​
```

Of course, you could also make your own `specialitemize` environment that does the same:

```
\newenvironment{specialitemize}
  {\itemize\specialitems}% \begin{specialitemize}
  {\enditemize}% \end{specialitemize}
```

Now you can use

```
\begin{specialitemize}
\item item one
\reditem item two
\item item three
\end{specialitemize}
```

Comment: Why do you use `leavevmode`? I've never understood exactly what's it for.

Comment: @NVaughan: You have to enter horizontal mode for the alignment to be proper - TeX builds up a page by placing stuff in boxes... horizontal boxes, which are then stacked on top of one another into a vertical list. Without that, you sometimes run into vertical box issues. See what happens when you *don't* use `\leavevmode` in the `itemize` environment (part of `\AddLinkToFile`) of the answer to [Adjust vertical spacing in tabular containing `\href`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75776/5764). Then there's also [Function and usage of `\leavevmode`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22852/5764).