# Hyperlinks Vertical Alignment Inside tabulary

Tags: tables, hyperref, vertical-alignment, tabulary

When trying to create a table using `tabulary` as:

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabulary}{6in}{rCJ}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Thing} & \textbf{Another} & \textbf{Thing} \\
    \midrule
    DEF & \hyperlink{def:ABC_DEF}{\texttt{ABC\_DEF}} & Some letters going on over here. \\
    GHIJKL & \hyperlink{def:ABC_GHI}{\texttt{ABC\_GHI}} \hyperlink{def:ABC_JKL}{\texttt{ABC\_JKL}} & This box has enough text inside of it to do some word wrapping I should hope, as that's what happens in my table. \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

the table entries that are hyperlinks show up as being aligned with the bottom of the cell such that they're offset from the other text in the same row (i.e. `DEF` is above `ABC_DEF` in the table).  When I remove the `hyperlink`s, however, the text in the rows are all aligned.

Is there any way I can use hyperlinks in a 'C' column of `tabulary` and maintain vertical alignment?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: and it's always best to make a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) :)

Comment: I don't think the text changes its vertical position; the boxes might create this illusion, but the text keeps its baseline.

Comment: Related Question: [Adjust vertical spacing in tabular containing \href](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75776/adjust-vertical-spacing-in-tabular-containing-href).

Answer (score 5):

But the text is aligned; the boxes from the hyperlinks extend downwards, but the vertical position of the text remains unaltered, as can be seen with some auxiliary lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabulary}{6in}{rCJ}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Thing} & \textbf{Another} & \textbf{Thing} \\
    \midrule
    DEF & \hyperlink{def:ABC_DEF}{\texttt{ABC\_DEF}} & Some letters going on over here. \\
    GHIJKL & \hyperlink{def:ABC_GHI}{\texttt{ABC\_GHI}} \hyperlink{def:ABC_JKL}{\texttt{ABC\_JKL}} & This box has enough text inside of it to do some word wrapping I should hope, as that's what happens in my table. \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabulary}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[blue] (0,31.5pt)  -- +(\textwidth,0);
\draw[blue] (0,19.3pt)  -- +(\textwidth,0);
\draw[blue] (0,8pt)  -- +(\textwidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps you could suppress the hyperlink boxes using some of the `hyperref` options, as in, for example, `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=cyan]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabulary}{6in}{rCJ}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Thing} & \textbf{Another} & \textbf{Thing} \\
    \midrule
    DEF & \hyperlink{def:ABC_DEF}{\texttt{ABC\_DEF}} & Some letters going on over here. \\
    GHIJKL & \hyperlink{def:ABC_GHI}{\texttt{ABC\_GHI}} \hyperlink{def:ABC_JKL}{\texttt{ABC\_JKL}} & This box has enough text inside of it to do some word wrapping I should hope, as that's what happens in my table. \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to keep the boxes, but making them tighter, you can use **Heiko Oberdiek**'s suggestions in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77595/3954) to [\ref with tight box surrounding the reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69378/3954):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\hypersetup{pdflinkmargin=0pt}
  \begin{tabulary}{6in}{rCJ}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Thing} & \textbf{Another} & \textbf{Thing} \\
    \midrule
    DEF & \mbox{\hyperlink{def:ABC_DEF}{\texttt{ABC\_DEF}}} & Some letters going on over here. \\
    GHIJKL & \hyperlink{def:ABC_GHI}{\texttt{ABC\_GHI}} \mbox{\hyperlink{def:ABC_JKL}{\texttt{ABC\_JKL}}} & This box has enough text inside of it to do some word wrapping I should hope, as that's what happens in my table. \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Ugly red frames I would say. Is it possible to do it closer?

Comment: @Sigur what do you mean? Do you mean to have the boxes tighter?

Comment: Yes, like `\fbox`.

Comment: @Sigur one can use `\hypersetup{pdflinkmargin=0pt}` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77595/3954) but if the surrounding boxes have descenders the hyperlink boxes will still have depth.

Comment: @Sigur please see the last example in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and for making my example into a working one.  Weirdly, when I run the example (copied and pasted from what you've posted to ensure no differences), I get a vertical alignment problem again. [Screenshot here.](http://imgur.com/B1x56)

Comment: I found a solution within the provided links, thank you!  I ended up using \leavevmode\smash{\hyperlink{...}{...}} for the links, which produces the desired result locally.